# Python How to check the string is a UTC timestamp?

Tags: python-3.x, datetime, datetime-format, python-datetime, pytz

I need to check if the string of timestamp belongs to 'UTC' timestamp

i have below code

```
def time_stamp():
    utc = timezone('UTC')
    time_stamp = datetime.now(utc)
    utc_time_stmap = time_stamp.strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f")
    return utc_time_stmap
```

the above function return the utc time in a string format

```
print(type(time_stamp()))
<class 'str'>

print(time_stamp())
'2021-02-10 15:49:57.906168'
```

The 'time_stamp()' return the timestamp in 'string type'.

#Expected:

i need to check the return value falls within a tight date UTC date range?

Appreciated for the the help?

Thanks

Comment: There is no timezone information in that string. What you ask (creating information out of nowhere) is not possible (at least in the world of programming)

Comment: could you please clarify: what do you mean be "*utc date time format*"? [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)? A string like `2021-02-10 15:49:57.906168` has neither time zone information nor UTC offset, how would you determine if it represents UTC?

Comment: Hi Pranva and MrFuppes, i have update the question with expected, i need to check the return time stamp is current utc time stamp..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you get some code where you may find your answer.

```
import re
from datetime import datetime

DATETIME_ISO8601 = re.compile(
    r'^([0-9]{4})' r'-' r'([0-9]{1,2})' r'-' r'([0-9]{1,2})' # date
    r'([T\s][0-9]{1,2}:[0-9]{1,2}:?[0-9]{1,2}(\.[0-9]{1,6})?)?' # time
    r'((\+[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2})| UTC| utc)?' # zone
)

def datetime_iso(string):
    """ verify rule
    Mandatory is: 'yyyy-(m)m-(d)dT(h)h:(m)m'        
    """
    string = string.strip()
    return bool(re.fullmatch(DATETIME_ISO8601, string))

def utc_timezone(datetime_string):
    datetime_string = datetime_string.strip()
    return datetime_string.endswith("00:00") or datetime_string.upper().endswith("UTC")


check_this = ["2020-1-1 22:11", "2020-1-1 22:11:34 00:00", "2020-1-1 22:11:34+00:00", "2020-1-1 22:11+01:00", "2020-1-1 22:11 UTC", "does this help?"]

for datetime_string in check_this:
    print(".........................")
    print(f"This date time string '{datetime_string}' is in datetime iso format: {datetime_iso(datetime_string)}")
    if datetime_iso(datetime_string):
        print(f"Is it the UTC time zone? {utc_timezone(datetime_string)}")
```